# How to use call_once() correctly in a constructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The following [program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e63cfd9ca5d4db73) tries to use **call_once**() in a constructor. It is a modification of an example provided by Stroustrup in "CPL", 4.

```
class X
{
private:
   static int data;
   static once_flag initdata_flg;

   static void init();

public:
   X()
   {
      call_once(initdata_flg, init);

      cout << "** diagnostic: X::data initialized"
           << endl; 
   }

   int getdata() const
   {
      return data;
   }
};


/** class X static members ...
    (static members must be defined 
    outside the class **/
int X::data;
once_flag X::initdata_flg;

void X::init()
{
   data = 915;
}


/// declarations ...
void construct();

/// implementation ...

int main()
{
   thread t1 {construct};
   thread t2 {construct};

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}

void construct()
{
    X x;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
** diagnostic: X::data initialized
** diagnostic: X::data initialized
```

The diagnostic appears twice, rather than once. Clearly, this is not how to use **call_once**() correctly in a constructor.

For this to work, I would need to use **call_once**() in the *construct()* function. That's not what I want to do. I want to use **call_once**() in the *constructor*.

What is the right way to do so?

Comment: Move your diagnostic output into the `init` function, because this is the function that should be called once. Your output is in the constructor and will therefore always be printed when you construct an `X` object.

Comment: excuse me, you create TWO instances of X. each instance calls `call_once()` and print diagnostics. What do you expect? Comstructor is called each time you create X. If you need a singleton, USE singleton pattern.

Comment: @pschill, that was spot on. It [works perfectly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3768d85d5049a8a7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're issuing the diagnostic in the consturctor, not in `init`. Of course the constructor will run twice; it will always run once for each object you create. However, only one of the calls to `call_once` will actually call `init`, which you can verify by moving the diagnostic output there.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33b6e622d952ec9a)

Comment: Any access to the guarded data need be accessed trough a "call_once". So, you should have pointed out proper modification to "getdata" too.

Comment: @Red.Wave I don't quite understand. How could all future accesses be guarded through a `call_once`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: How can you make sure "data" is properly initialized before first call to "getdata"?

Comment: @Red.Wave The constructor of the second and subsequent `X` will wait in `call_once` for the first to finish (or fail with an exception, which isn't possible in this example)

Comment: @Caleth I see; "getdata" is not static and you need an object to access it.